# SciFi book: Earth split between Ant-Bee-Wasp alliance and The Rats

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

Many years from now, the Earth and Moon have been clobbered by a massive cosmic strike. Humans have survived for centuries in underground hibernation chambers. When they emerge, they find that the Earth is split between the Ant + Bee + Wasp alliance and The Rats. Under the surviving Prime Coordinator, the humans ally with the alliance against the (**vile**) militaristic Rats.
In space there is a fleet of space ships that have just woken up; once the human guinea pigs in terrestrial hibernation have "tested the water+air" they plan to grab the Earth for themselves.
But the Earth environment is now lethal to them - high UV etc.

Comment: Looks like duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/203237/1970s-book-where-humans-awake-from-hibernation-to-find-ants-and-bees-have-evolv, with the answer "Sold - for a spaceship" by Philip E High

Comment: Does this answer your question? [1970's book where humans awake from hibernation to find ants and bees have evolved into intelligent beings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/203237/1970s-book-where-humans-awake-from-hibernation-to-find-ants-and-bees-have-evolv)

Comment: @KMo The answer here has not been confirmed to be correct and so it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Apologies. I misread the comment on the answer as being from the OP.

Answer (score 15):

[*Sold-for a Spaceship*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/6062965) by Philip E High

They had slept in safety while destruction raged above them. When they awoke and emerged from their places of refuge, the world had changed - totally.
For man soon discovered that he was no longer the dominant species on Earth. Now there were other creatures, not only ready to dispute the point but well prepared to prove it.
It was later, much later, that the bulk of mankind discovered they had forfeited their birthright, traded their home, the planet Earth - for a spaceship.

Sample text: [*books.google.com*](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=Y9_VuskJfE8C&pg=PT55&lpg=PT55&dq=%22if+ants+formed+a+mutual+agreement%22&source=bl&ots=9v6u_e1Kfp&sig=ACfU3U1w8UQyqOZv5fQ5Rw9zSisOOqNSnQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQ4dLZraTsAhUDxYsKHaj0BVQQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22if%20ants%20formed%20a%20mutual%20agreement%22&f=false)

Comment: Yes, I have the book and it's a perfect match to the description in the question.